# When I put a bit in GPSET to 1, what is the actual mechanism that "reads" this register and put the electric line to HIGH Voltage? Who does this? How?

Tags: gpio, relay, peripherals, signal

I don't know what is the actual mechanism.

When the CPU sets that register(GPSET)'s bit to 1, what entity/element reads that and is responsible to activate the electric line to HIGH? How is this done?

Comment: It is an electronic device.  Perhaps study electronics if you want to know how it works.

Comment: Start by learning what a transistor is and how they are used to implement logic gates.

Comment: @joan thanks for your amazing help. I studied electronics, but I don't have studied the mechanism in the question. so if you want to help, just redirect me to some keyword so that I can investigate.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for your amazing help. I studied electronics, but I don't have studied the mechanism in the question. so if you want to help, just redirect me to some keyword so that I can investigate.

Comment: *"I studied electronics, but I don't have studied the mechanism in the question*" o_O https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_register ...Like I said, transistors (mostly).  There's nothing special about the GPIOs, they are the same as the elementary components of any MC or processor that carry a signal (so, very basic electronics wise): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output  Something else to consider: [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)